# HTML div centering doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I just started to follow some simple video about web site development.
Since I don't want to just go through instructions given, I stumbled upon small issue: why `div id="header"` is not centered even with option `margin: 0 auto`, declared in css? Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>FLASTER</title>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"> -->

<style>

body {
    background: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial";  
}

#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    background: white;
    border-left: 5px solid blue;
    border-right: 5px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;  
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;   

    border-left: 3px solid blue;
    border-right: 3px solid blue;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">   

</div> <!-- End of header -->

<div id="content">



</div> <!-- End of content -->

<div id="footer">

</div> <!-- End of footer -->

</div> <!-- End of wrapper -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i put your code into js fiddle....and it actually works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/326/, yes your css looks a little weird, but the header is centered...

Comment: @indubitablee — The code in the JS Fiddle is different to the code in the question. `box-sizing` has been added.

Comment: Margin: 0 auto only wok when the position is relative.

Comment: @urlator (nice nick, btw;)), what you actually want??? header is centered on page, because it is inside wrapper with fixed width. Few pixels are problem because of default box model behavior, which could be fixed with applying of box-sizing:border-box.... But, not sure that you talk about that few pixels....

Comment: @PayerAhammed — That's untrue.

Comment: @nevermind thanks man (hvala) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto margins will centre the box (including the padding and the border) so long as the total width of it is 100% or less. (If it is exactly 100% then centred, left-aligned and right-aligned will look identical.).

The header element is not centred for two reasons:

1. It doesn't have `margin: 0 auto`
2. Even if it did, the box has a content-width of 100% and 6 pixels of borders as well, so it ends up being left aligned with the right-most 6 pixels being pushed out to the right.

If you set `width: auto` then it will adjust the content width to fill the container (accounting for the borders) which will centre it on the page (since its container is centred).

Comment: Actually, it is centered, it is inside wrapper with fixed width:960px. Or, i didn't understand OPs question :)

Comment: @nevermind  The wrapper is centred. The header is not centred within the wrapper and sticks out 6px to the right of the wrapper so it isn't centred within the page either.

Comment: Not sure, lets wait OP... seems centered to me: http://jsfiddle.net/hkzhs3fL/ (after box-sizing applied, of course)

Comment: @nevermind — After box-sizing is applied in a way that *it isn't in the question*?

Comment: @Quentin hey man, thanks. width: auto solved the problem. one question though, since header is inside wrapper, shouldn't header inherit margin: 0 auto from  wrapper css? also, I didn't quite understand why in the first case element was pushed to the right side. could you elaborate that just a little bit more?

Comment: *shouldn't header inherit margin: 0 auto* — Only if you set `margin: inherit` (which isn't the default).

Comment: 3px + 100% + 3px is more than 100%. auto margins with content that is more than 100% of the container are left aligned. The extra 6px have to go somewhere.

Comment: @Quentin thanks. I just tested with some other values and figure out what you were saying. all the best.

Answer (score 0):

It has `width: 100%`, so, what to center? Set a width less than 100% (for ex. 50%), add `text-align: center;` to its parent (#wrapper ) and see the result.

```
    #wrapper {
      text-align: center
    }
    #header {
      width: 50%;
      border: 3px solid blue;
      margin: 3px auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `width: 100%` in `#wrapper`or if you want maximum width you can set `max-width: 960px; width:100%;`

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%
    height: auto;
    background: white;
    border-left: 5px solid blue;
    border-right: 5px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;  
}
```

or

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 960px;
    width:100%
    height: auto;
    background: white;
    border-left: 5px solid blue;
    border-right: 5px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center a block, you must set it to a width less than 100% and use `margin:auto`.

If you want to center the content within a block, you use `text-align:center`.